# How do I extend logical partitions?

Tags: ubuntu, hard-drive, disk-space

I have 500GB of Harddisk space.

Following is the structure

```
Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System

/dev/sda1   *        2048      206847      102400    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2          206848    81922047    40857600    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3        81924094   292857855   105466881    5  Extended
/dev/sda5        81924096   277233663    97654784   83  Linux
/dev/sda6       277235712   292857855     7811072   82  Linux swap / Solaris
```

How do I extend my logical partition without affecting Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

Use GParted to edit your partitions.

http://gparted.sourceforge.net/

Comment: you can also install gparted via command line like so: 'sudo apt-get install gparted'

Comment: @godka That is a possibility, but I'd be more cautious when using gparted on a running system as opposed to using a LiveCD of gparted.

Comment: indeed @Kruug, much safer with some partitioning distro

Comment: @Kruug gparted can be used but will it affect exisitng Ubuntu?

Comment: @Akhil as long as you don't extend into your Ubuntu, you'll be fine.  If you don't need the entire space of the 2 NTFS partitions, you can shrink, slide, then expand.

Answer (score 0):

Check out `Hiren's Boot CD`, it has a lot of great tools.
You can boot off it, choose one of the partitioning softwares and partition your system anyway you like it.